# Can I write a SQL query that creates a default value in a Data Extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, system-fields

I'd like to query the CLICK system table for members who clicked a certain URL string (for example, http://www.store.com/men) and assign a default value to those members.

My initial thought was to find members are per the above and then write to a Data Extension (as per a Query activity) called "men_clicks" and assign a default value of 1 in "men_clicks" field (with the other field being email address).

Is this possible?  I'm not a SQL guru by any stretch.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
    SubscriberKey,
    JobID
    Case URL
        When 'http://www.store.com/men' Then 'men_clicks'
        When 'http://www.store.com/women' Then 'women_clicks'
        Else 'NA'
    End
From _Click
Where DateDiff(d,EventDate,GetDate()) < 30
```

Something like the above should work. You're essentially in need of a CASE statement. 
The DateDiff() is added, and I'd recommend in order to reduce the load. Depending on your setup, and how long that URL has been in use, it might take a long time to load results.